# Elasticsearch query with jQuery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, elasticsearch

Today I have a problem with ElasticSearch and jQuery. I've searched for solution, but I found no solution.

I want to get some data from ElasticSearch using jQuery. It works when I use curl instead:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/locations/_search?pretty=true" -d '
{
   "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": { 
          "lat" :  40.715,
          "lon": -73.998
        },
        "order":         "asc",
        "unit":          "km", 
        "distance_type": "plane" 
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

but it doesn't work when I use jQuery. I tried:

```
var data = {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "1km", 
          "location": { 
            "lat" :  40.715,
            "lon": -73.998
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:9200/locations/_search?pretty=true",
  crossDomain: true,  
  async: false,
  data: data,
  dataType : 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
})
.done(function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
})
.fail(function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I tried to pass data with JSON.stringify(data) and it also doesn't work. I even tried to change method from "GET" to "POST" and no results. Well, it's working. ElasticSearch returns a response with some locations, but my locations are far far away from location I requested. 40.715, -73.998 location is New York and when I use curl it returns locations in New York, but when I use jQuery I get locations in Mexico so I think my "data" variable is ignored. I mentioned I tried to use json.Stringify. Yes, but it returns error:

```
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/y.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/y.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/y.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/y.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/y.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/y.abort(), state: .Deferred/e.state(), always: .Deferred/e.always(), catch: .Deferred/e.catch(),… }
```

So, how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, problem resolved. My code is okay. I changed method to "POST". Using Google Chrome Developer Tools I noticed that the other part of code wasn't good. In my code

```
"location": { 
   "lat" :  40.715,
   "lon": -73.998
}
```

lat and lon was a variables (I changed them to coords for StackOverflow question) wchich was empty, because the other part of my code couldn't assign a new value from getCurrentPosition() (default value was 0, that's why my code didn't work). So, correct version of the code is:

```
var data = {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "1km", 
          "location": { 
            "lat" :  lat,
            "lon": lon
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:9200/locations/_search?pretty=true",
  crossDomain: true,  
  async: false,
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  dataType : 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
})
.done(function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
})
.fail(function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Notice that lat and lon are variables which need parameters to be a geopoint